# HIghCharts dual axes combo

Tags: highcharts, combinations

I am trying out http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes.
While this works, i am trying to get the data loaded from a csv using the data module. By default, the 1st column is the name, and the columns thereafter contain the data. Is there a way to insert the type column in there?

```
series: [{
            name: 'Rainfall',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' mm'
            }

        }, {
            name: 'Temperature',
            type: 'spline',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            }
        }]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the data.src.js module you cannot specify yAxis, so you need to load CSV file and parse it on your own, pushing yAxis parameter.